# Moq Verify fails to match repeated method calls on changed object

Tags: callback, installation, moq, verify

I need to test that a repository Save() method is called twice with the same object but where the object's properties have been changed between invocations.

The SUT code boils down to:

```
        Person person = _repos.Load(name);

        person.Age = age1;
        _repos.Save(person);
        person.Age = age2;
        _repos.Save(person);
```

The UT code is:

```
        // Arrange
        Mock<IRepository> repo = new Mock<IRepository>();

        repo.Setup(m => m.Load(It.IsAny<String>())).Returns(new Person { Name = "Jim", Age = 20 });
        repo.Setup(m => m.Save(It.Is<Person>(p => p.Age == 21))).Callback(() =>
            {
                Debug.Print("Age = 21");
            });
        repo.Setup(m => m.Save(It.Is<Person>(p => p.Age == 22))).Callback(() =>
            {
                Debug.Print("Age = 22");
            }).Returns(1);
        var service = new ABCService(repo.Object);

        // Act
        service.ChangeAge("Jim", 21, 22);

        // Assert
        repo.Verify(m => m.Save(It.Is<Person>(p => p.Age == 22)), Times.Once); 
        repo.Verify(m => m.Save(It.Is<Person>(p => p.Age == 21)), Times.Once);
```

When executing the test the two separate Callbacks are hit as expected.  However, the first verify fails because Moq believes it was called twice while the second verify fails as not called.

It appears that the properties of the Person object parameter that is used in both Save() calls are not preserved at the point of method invocation. Instead it appears to be just holding a reference to the Person parameter and checking its properties after all invocations.

Is there a way to get round this? The only thing I can think of is to take copies of object properties in multiple Setup.Callbacks (replacing the Debug.Print statements). However, it would be nicer not to have .Setups at all as the Save() method has nothing to return.

Comment: Your question is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960728/moq-verifying-a-call-with-parameter-that-is-changed-during-the-execution-of-th), and your workaround is mentioned there in the accepted answer.  That said, I'd like to see a better way too.

Comment: Yes - it is pretty much the same problem. The solution I'm using now is to add .Verifiable() on to the .Setup()s and not doing repo.Verify in the //Assert section. Not ideal as you can't use the Times.Once specifier but it is good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is an error in Moq which you could report at github:
https://github.com/Moq/moq4

However I would solve this by skipping the two call to Verify with VerifyAll();
Similar to [the solved issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960728/moq-verifying-a-call-with-parameter-that-is-changed-during-the-execution-of-th) pointed out by Patrick Qurik.

```
  // Arrange
  Mock<IRepository> repo = new Mock<IRepository>();

  repo.Setup(m => m.Load(It.IsAny<String>())).Returns(new Person { Name = "Jim", Age = 20 });
  repo.Setup(m => m.Save(It.Is<Person>(p => p.Age == 21)));
  repo.Setup(m => m.Save(It.Is<Person>(p => p.Age == 22)));

  var service = new ABCService(repo.Object);

  // Act
  service.ChangeAge("Jim", 21, 22);

  // Assert
  repo.VerifyAll();
```